# Delphi ^A syntax: Documented, implied, or undocumented?

Tags: delphi, syntax, keyboard, character

Let me explain by an example. In Delphi, you can write

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = ^C then
    ShowMessage('The user wants to copy something.')
  else if Key = ^V then
    ShowMessage('The user wants to paste.')
end;
```

to check for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V keyboard commands. In fact, the same syntax works for Ctrl+A, where A is *any* character, and -- of course -- you can also use a `case` statement instead of `if`s. You can even do `ShowMessage(^A)`, so, apparently, `^A` is considered a `char`.

However, when browsing [the official Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Language_Guide_Index), I cannot find any reference to this syntax. But maybe the `^A` syntax is so common that it is understood as a part of the underlying plain text file format? Or is it simply an undocumented feature of the Delphi programming language? (Notice that the above constructions are actually used in the RTL/VCL source code. But, of course, Embarcadero, and Embarcadero alone, is allowed to use undocumented features, if any such exists.)

Comment: anyone can use undocumented features

Comment: @David: OK, I agree that the problem isn't nearly as bad as in the case of the Windows API, for instance.

Comment: Some of them, error insight don't like, like `^[` (Esc), `^@` (NUL)..

Comment: Yet again I learn something new from SO (after 13 using Delphi!)

Comment: [Pascal ISO 7185:1990](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/iso7185.pdf) has [ISO/IEC 646](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_646) as a normative reference (page 7), which originally defined [C0 control codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). Maybe that's a way to say that it could be implied.

Comment: @Gerry, don't worry. You'r not alone. Funny thing is that I see them all over the place when using vim but had no idea it could be used in Delphi.

Comment: @Sertac: did you QC those issues? I think you should make that ISO thing an answer too; I'll definitely vote for that.

Comment: @Jeroen - Nope, I don't QC for a few years now... As for answering the question, IMO yours is better since AFAIK Borland never claimed that their pascal adhered to any standard at all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is from long ago as an escape character to enable you to have consts for control characters in a more readable way.

```
const
  CtrlC = ^C;
begin
  Write(Ord(CtrlC));
end.
```

This defines a Char constant with value `#3`, then writes `3` in Borland Pascal 7, and I remember seeing it years before that too.

I just checked the Turbo Pascal 5.0 and Borland Pascal 7.0 languages guides, but could not find it, so it seems undocumented.

**Edit:**
I do remember this was a Borland thing, and just [checked](http://www.moorecad.com/standardpascal/iso7185.pdf): it is not part of the ISO Pascal standard (formerly this was ANSI Pascal Standard, thanks Sertac for noticing this).

[It](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu6.html#x29-320003.2.1) **is** documented in the [Free Pascal documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse8.html#x20-190001.8).

SGI uses the backslash as escape character, as [per their docs](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi/0640/bks/SGI_Developer/books/Pascal_PG/sgi_html/ch01.html).

**More Edit:** I found it [documented in Delphi in a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=tCKRewN1hioC&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=delphi+control+character+constants&source=bl&ots=dUgiDnUoWP&sig=qA3xE2l16N5ux7JpBMjsD-jKoIY&hl=en&ei=6hZPTeC4B4GAOobKzCM&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) and the [Delphi Basics site](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Char).

**Found it:** Just found it on page 37 of the [Turbo Pascal 3 Reference Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/TURBO_Pascal_Reference_Manual_CPM_Version_3_Dec88.pdf).

--jeroen

Comment: There's no ANSI standard on the pascal language since 1993, when ANSI terminated it on behalf of the ISO standard. Regarding the ISO standard see my comment to Andreas' question.

Comment: Afaik when there were talks about simplifying the (Delphi) compiler a few years back, this feature, together with stuff like (.  .) was used as examples

Comment: Edited comment that provides FPC documentation link (IT)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort did those FPC pages change? As currently, they only document the `#` syntax to create control characters.

Comment: Yes, In case topics move or get split, links can die. I had to go "up" and then to the topic/section before. Updated link.

Comment: It's also mentioned on page 45 in [Turbo Pascal Version 2.0 Reference](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/Turbo_Pascal_Version_2.0_Reference_1984.pdf).

Comment: Fun fact: The 2.0 link is one of the manuals with the `CASE ... OF ... OTHERWISE ... END` typo. At page 233. It never was OTHERWISE, it always was ELSE from the beginning.

Comment: For the ones interested: the `otherwise` keyword is documented in the Turbo Pascal 1 through 3 versions of the reference manuals which you can find as PDF files at http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/ Hard to find with Google Search because of the OCR inserted random spaces in the text, see https://www.google.com/search?q=case+otherwise+statement+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bitsavers.org%2Fpdf%2Fborland%2Fturbo_pascal%2F

Answer (score 3):

This is a known undocumented feature. But then again, the latest official syntax documentation is from delphi 7.

Comment: could you describe it. What is the type of ^A?

Comment: Right, it's a Char and ord(^A)=1, ^G is the bell!

Comment: @David, its type is "string literal," the same as if you'd used `#1`. The compiler will treat it as a char or string as context dictates. It's valid in all versions of Delphi, and many, if not all, versions of Turbo Pascal.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: +1, for from Turbo Pascal it has been inherited. I remember it very well being described in TP/BP's help system.

Comment: I used it in turbo pascal 5.5 some hundred years ago... it was useful to write(^G) at that times to notify the user about wrong things... you can still go to cmd.exe and "execute" the ctrl+G. :p  @David, you made me remember a lot of old things... hehe. :D.  BTW, it must be AnsiChar not char... right?