# Why does unchecking "Enable runtime themes" disables select all by Ctrl + A?

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-10, delphi-2007, windows-themes

I've created a new VCL application and placed a `TEdit` control on the form.

At runtime, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut to select all the text of the `TEdit`.

As soon as I switched the "Enable runtime themes" option off from the Project Options, I've noticed that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> keyboard shortcut stopped working.

[image: enable runtime themes]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Any application that will run on XP and newer Windows should have runtime themes enabled. Do you really need to support pre-XP Windows?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: No, I was just "playing" with project options and I have been surprised about that

Comment: Related: [win32 select all on edit ctrl (textbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291792/). It is geared towards MFC, but would apply to Delphi, too.

Comment: CTRL+A doesn't work at all in a `TMemo` control, even with runtime themes enabled.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466747/automatically-allowing-ctrla-to-select-all-in-a-tmemo Sometimes you just have to write more code than you anticipated.

Comment: Presumably that shortcut is only handled by comctl32 v6 and up versions of the edit control