# Why can the circumflex sign be used for control chars in Delphi and is it a good idea?

Tags: delphi, syntax, history

I just came across an answer on SO with a curious syntax:

[How do I include a newline character in a string in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254407/how-do-i-include-a-newline-character-in-a-string-in-delphi)

`MyString := 'Hello,' + ^M + ^J + 'world!';`

I've been using Delphi for several years now, but I didn't know you could use the circumflex sign for control characters.

Is this just a left over from the early Delphi or Turbo Pascal days?

Should it be used nowadays?

PS: I'm not asking about advice on the line break characters, there is sLineBreak and other methods as discussed in the original question.

Comment: Never ever seen this before, +1 for good question

Comment: I just noticed that it's a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915941/delphi-a-syntax-documented-implied-or-undocumented

Comment: It is a left over from Turbo Pascal.

Comment: Isn't that syntax easily confused with pointers? Or are ^M and ^J pointers?

Comment: @PieterB And that's why having single character variable names is not a good idea. ;-)

Comment: @PieterB No, this is not pointer syntax. You can use PType = ^Type in a type declaration and dereference pointers in code using MyPointer^.

Comment: Also getting the adress of a var uses the @ syntax.

Comment: @PieterB But you can't use a type in a const section. You also can't use a constant in a type section. It may look ambiguous, but on closer inspection it isn't.

Comment: Well of course you can use a type in a const section if you use the `Constant: TSomeType = ` syntax :).

Comment: @golez single character names for local loop variables is just fine. I'd always use i, j and k as my loop variable names for a matrix mul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is a legacy from days of yore.

And no you should not get into the habit of using this feature. Remember that code is read more often than it is written. Always think of your readers who most likely won't know what that syntax means.

Comment: The good ol' days of yore I presume? (I wasn't old enough to code back then, but it sounds like the past of Delphi development was awesome'r that it is now)

Comment: @Jeff, you're right about that, but this construct is from the days before Delphi was Delphi. :)

Comment: and before Pascal was Turboed!

Answer (score 9):

No, it is not from Turbo Pascal days. It is from decades before TP, and before MS-DOS, and probably even before UNIX. Something old like first 300 bit-per-second dialup modems and DEC VT-52 terminal, RT-8 OS on PDP-8 machine and early version of C. Or maybe even older - though everything older to me is mere legends :-).

"^" sign is shortcut for "Ctrl" key. So `^C` in traditional notation stands for `Ctrl+C` in Microsoft notation. That notation was vastly used for textmode menus in MS-DOS times, like in the aforementioned Turbo Pascal, Norton Utilities, DOS Navigator, etc.

Out of my memory you can consider "^" for "subtract 64".
So as `Chr(65)` is `'A'` then `Chr(1)` would be `^A`.
And `^@` would be `#0` :-) AFAIR in MS-DOS times pressing Ctrl+Shift+"2/@" would actually produce `#0` into BIOS keyboard buffer :-)

^[ would AFAIR be `#27` aka Esc(ape) char - and if you run `telnet.exe` you would see it prompted as the escape character.

So Turbo Pascal long ago chosen to follow the time-blessed convention, and then rules of backward compatibility engaged ever since. Personally, i take `'bla-bla'^M^J'foo-baz'` literal more string-like than `'bla-bla'#13#10'foo-baz'` when you want it on one line. And constructing the value with plus is better fit when your literal takes several source lines.

The pity is that syntax highlighting in Delphi IDE is hopelessly broken on that kind of constants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is left over from TP days. You could also write your statement like this

```
mystring:= 'Hello'#13#10'world!';
```

which is probably less obscure and more easily understandable than using ^M and ^J. Of course, you should really define constants

```
const
 crlf = #13#10

begin
 mystring:= 'Hello' + crlf + 'world!';
end;
```

Comment: You have `sLineBreak` if we are talking about defining constants ;-)

Comment: Also using "sLineBreak" will make the code "Cross Platform Aware" as it has different meaning on Windows and Mac :)