# What does this Delphi syntax do? "someAnsiChar := ^H;"

Tags: delphi, char, control-characters

I am converting a really old component into Delphi 12 and have stumbled across syntax I don't recall seeing before. The code is a bit like this:

```
someBoolean := key in [^H, #32..#255];
```

I get that it's testing if `key` matches, or is within range, of the specified set of ANSI characters, but what exactly is `^H`? Delphi seems happy to compile the line if I change `H` for `A`, `B`, `C` or `1`. The line compiles under Delphi 12 and Delphi 7. I can't seem to find anything about this. It seems like a really old syntax, maybe from Pascal days. Can anyone shed some light on this please?

I've prepared this test code in Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15: AnsiChar;
begin
  c1 := ^A;
  c2 := ^B;
  c3 := ^C;
  c4 := ^D;
  c5 := ^E;
  c6 := ^F;
  c7 := ^G;
  c8 := ^H;
  c9 := ^Z;
  c10 := ^a;
  c11 := ^b;
  c12 := ^0;
  c13 := ^1;
  c14 := ^2;
  c15 := ^3;
  ShowMessage(
    IntToStr(Byte(c1)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c2)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c3)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c4)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c5)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c6)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c7)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c8)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c9)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c10)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c11)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c12)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c13)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c14)) + #13#10 +
    IntToStr(Byte(c15)));
end;
```

The output is this:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 26
> 1
> 2
> 112
> 113
> 114
> 115

So it looks like the characters in caps correspond to their position within the alphabet, but I can't tell what others correspond to. They don't match their corresponding values in the ASCII table.

Comment: from [doc](http://downloads.freepascal.org/fpc/docs-pdf/ref.pdf) `the caret character (^) can be used in combination with a letter to specify a character with ASCII value less than 27. Thus ^G equals #7 − G is the seventh letter in the alphabet.`

Comment: Thanks Ilya.  The link is for FPC, but it appears to be accurate for Delphi also. "The compiler is rather sloppy about the characters it allows after the caret, but in general one should assume only letters."

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915941/282848?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `^` represents the control key, and is a holdover from old Pascal (and before that, the ANSI terminal). The key would match Ctrl+H, which is a backspace. Essentially, the set  `[^H, #32..#255]` includes the backspace and any ASCII character above #32 (a space).

Some other common escape sequences in the ANSI terminal are:

General ASCII Codes, taken from [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

| Name | decimal | octal | hex | C-escape | Ctrl-Key | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BEL | 7 | 007 | 0x07 | \a | ^G | Terminal bell |
| BS | 8 | 010 | 0x08 | \b | ^H | Backspace |
| HT | 9 | 011 | 0x09 | \t | ^I | Horizontal TAB |
| LF | 10 | 012 | 0x0A | \n | ^J | Linefeed (newline) |
| VT | 11 | 013 | 0x0B | \v | ^K | Vertical TAB |
| FF | 12 | 014 | 0x0C | \f | ^L | Formfeed (also: New page NP) |
| CR | 13 | 015 | 0x0D | \r | ^M | Carriage return |
| ESC | 27 | 033 | 0x1B | \e* | ^[ | Escape character |
| DEL | 127 | 177 | 0x7F |  |  | Delete character |

Comment: Thanks Ken. At first I did think it meant the Ctrl key, having seen Telnet print a caret and the character pressed in the past (e.g. Ctrl+E). Just tried it with Telnet after seeing your answer and indeed Ctrl+H acts like a backspace! It made so little sense seeing this in Delphi's char set testing code. When I saw the 8 in my tests, backspace crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure. So 'M' being the 13th letter in the alphabet would correspond to carriage return. Makes sense. I certainly won't be using this syntax though, but good to know. Thank you

Comment: The [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) still carry those names in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set) and therefore also in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Control_pictures).